# Unable to pass a variable to a function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass the current index to a function reading images via FileApi and showing preview of them:

```
for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
    continue;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      var dv = document.createElement("div");
      //.............

    };
  })(f);

  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

I've tried this:

```
  //.......
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(theFile, i2) {

    //i2 is defined here

    return function(e) {
      var dv = document.createElement("div");

      //i2 isn't defined here



    };
  })(f, i);
```

But as you can see, i2 isn't defined. How to fix that?

Comment: `But as you can see, i2 isn't defined` - you say it isn't, but we can't see it isn't

Comment: Could you console.log(i) to see wheter its defined or not? This example:
`onload = function(f, i) { return function(e) { console.log(f, i); }}("filename", 2);onload()` shows it's defined

Comment: your code logic (as presented in the question) should work fine - as you can see in this dummied up fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/crohqc5a/ - perhaps you're doing something wrong in your **actual** code

Comment: @gilbertxenodike, everything is defined but i2

Comment: You're doing a lot of fancy tricks to rescope things and it's ending up reducing the scope beyond what you expected. Try to be less fancy with the scope and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

If you organize the wrapper function(s) a bit, everything can be properly scoped. Here I wrap basically the whole loop body in a self-calling function. The onload handler is then just a plain old function assignment. In your production code you can remove the dummy onload.

```js
var files = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    (function(i, f) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
            var dv = document.createElement("div");
            console.log(f + i);
        };
        // dummy onload
        (function(r) {
          setTimeout(r.onload, 1000 + (i + 1) * 333);
        })(reader);
    })(i, f)
}
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it fix the problem?